# Missing "energy saving" settings on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, energy-saving, system-preferences

[MacBook Pro - Official manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/macbook_Pro_15inch_Late2008.pdf):

> Your MacBook Pro comes with two
>   graphics processors, one for better
>   battery life and  the other for higher
>   performance. To switch between
>   processors, open System  Preferences,
>   click Energy Saver, **select “Better
>   battery life” or “Higher performance,”** [sic]
>   and  then follow the onscreen
>   instructions.

I followed the instructions and opened "System Preferences" -> "Energy Saver". However, there is neither a "Better battery life" nor a "Higher performance" to select.

What could have been the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout depends on which exact model you have. You can see in the URL that this is the manual for the late 2008 model, which was sold from 10/2008 to 01/2009. [See this list of manuals and select the one applicable for your machine](http://support.apple.com/manuals/#macbookpro).

On my early 2010 Macbook Pro, it looks like this (near the top):

[image]

Comment: the image in my system look exactly the one in your image EXCEPT i do not have Anything above the "Battery / Power Adapter" line..

Comment: i didn't buy this laptop.. i don't know which model it is. is there a way to check it?

Comment: @Pacerier Open the Apple menu, click *About This Mac*, then *More Info…*. On the right side, there's the *Model Identifier*, e.g. `MacBookPro6,2`. Download [MacTracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/) and search for that identifier. That's your model.

Comment: @Pacerier In the same program (*System Profiler*) you can view your installed graphics cards by selecting *Graphics/Displays* in the list on the left. I assume from your description that you have an older or less powerful Macbook Pro model with a single video card that is simply missing this option completely.

Comment: @Daniel Beck I have NVIDIA GeForce 320M VRAM 256 Mb. btw identifier is macbookpro7,1 processor name: intel core 2 duo. is this the 2010 version?

Comment: @Daniel Beck anyway doesn't mac tracker simply give me the information i can see in system profiler..

Comment: @Pacerier It's the 13 inch version of mid 2010 and has a single video card. The manual you linked to is for the 15 inch version of late 2008. You can see that it just doesn't apply to your machine. You don't have the hardware for it, so you don't have the preference.

Comment: heys how did you know which version I'm using

Comment: @Daniel Beck anyway doesn't mac tracker simply give me the information i can see in system profiler..

Comment: @Pacerier *"heys how did you know which version I'm using"* Enter `macbookpro7,1` in Mactracker. That's how I know.

Comment: @Daniel Beck btw my macbook is what people call snow leopard?

Comment: @Pacerier Should be. To be sure, open "About this Mac" again and check the version number. 10.5.x is Leopard, 10.6.x is Snow Leopard. Also, remember that your Mac and Mac OS X are completely different things, they just happen to be usually sold bundled. Snow Leopard refers to Mac OS X version 10.6 and has little to do with your hardware.

Comment: ok kool thx  =D .

Answer (score 0):

It might be because it was hidden (Mac does that sometimes) open up System Preferences> on the toolbar at the top click **View** under it should be a list of all your system...preferences... there should be energy savings.